# Fail to looked up view in views directory when deploy app to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ejs, internal-server-error

I've deployed my NodeJS app to Heroku and get this error: `Internal Server Error`. Then I look up the logs and find that `Error: Failed to lookup view "student.ejs" in views directory "/app/views"`.
My directory structure is:

> ```
>   /node_modules
>   /public
>   /views
>       student.ejs
>   app.js
>   packet.json
> ```

here is the versions of dependencies I used.

> ```
>  "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
>  "ejs": "^2.5.7",
>  "express": "^4.15.3",
>  "mongoose": "^4.10.2"
> ```

set up template engine and directory of view

> ```
>  app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
>  app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
>  app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');
> ```

render

> ```
>  res.render('student.ejs',{info:data});
> ```

The app can run well in localhost. Can somebody help me to solve this problem. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can help you, but I was getting a similar error when deploying to Heroku. In my case, the problem was that my local environment was running on Windows but Heroku deploys to Linux containers.

I solved the problem by removing some hard-coded paths and use path.join instead.

In your case, you should replace

```
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');
```

With

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Bear in my mind that you will have to require the path module.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a view called createSession.hbs.

In my route createSession.js I was doing

`res.render('createsession', {...});`

On local the capital 'S' didn't matter but when deployed I was getting the Internal Server Error.

So the fix was to change createSession.hbs to createsession.hbs (lower case 's').

My local OS was Windows and I deployed on Heroku (Ubuntu server).

Stupid error and annoying error as it worked locally but hope it helps someone.